# "%matplotlib inline" doesn't display unicode characters

Tags: python, matplotlib, unicode

It does show them properly in the OSX backend mode. However, when I save a plot as png, the resulting image has empty squares instead, similar to the inline mode.
Switching to TeX or ASCII codes won't fix the problem since the strings to be displayed will come from a file.
Thanks!

Comment: You description of the problem is vague. Try to state clearly what your problem is. Maybe give a succinct code sample will be better.